# Can't find question when marking a duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I'm trying to mark [dataSource is getting null after first call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902539/datasource-is-getting-null-after-first-call) as a duplicate of [Grails datasource becoming null in Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620448/grails-datasource-becoming-null-in-service) .

So on the first question I flag it and it is asking me to select which question it is a duplicate of. I type the exact title of the question and it tells me it can't find any results! Yet I wrote the question's title exactly!

Comment: You can just paste the url in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be by design, not a bug.

It doesn't come up in the list because the question has **no upvoted or accepted answers** (classified as an "unanswered" question) and is therefore ineligible to be a duplicate target.

As Andrew Barber noted, you can just paste the URL into the box (which would tell you the reason outlined above):

> [image]

Comment: Oh, well that's good to know.